# Wordpress get all attributes and values

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Actually I have custom attributes in product for after this create searches for these attributes , the case it´s I try show all attributes and values but no get finally

For example actually I have the attribute called colors, in this attribute I have different values, **red, green yellow, blue**

**For show the attributes and his values i use this code :**

> ```
>     <?php    global $product;
> $terms=get_terms('pa_colors');
> print "<select>";
> foreach ($terms as $each_term) {
> echo '<option>'.$each_term->name.'</option>';
> } 
> print "</select>"; ?>
> ```

The case it´s this function only show me 2 colors and no the rest of colors, I see in the woocommerce backend I have only 2 products and have these colors that show with this function , but no the other colors, the case it´s in the backend of woocommerce for attributes I can see all attributes and colors and I want show the same as backend but in front, but this function no let me show all values for this attribute called colors.

How do I use only 2 color from attribute called colors only show me these 2 colors but no the others.

My question is, how can I show all colors or all values from one attribute in the front?

```
The result must be this :

<select>
<option>Red</option>
<option>Green</option>
<option>Yellow</option>
<option>Blue</option>
</select>
```

Thanks for the help. Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `get_terms()`, WordPress filters out terms that aren't attached to *published* posts (and WooCommerce stores your products as posts). Luckily, WordPress will allow you to prevent this from happening. Try the following:

```
$options = array('hide_empty' => false);

$terms = get_terms('pa_colors', $options);
```

Many other options are explained in the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

Answer (score 1):

Use this SQL Query to get all attributes with details

```
    global $wpdb;

    $attribute_taxonomies = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies WHERE attribute_name != '' ORDER BY attribute_name ASC;" );
    set_transient( 'wc_attribute_taxonomies', $attribute_taxonomies );

    $attribute_taxonomies = array_filter( $attribute_taxonomies  ) ;

    prin_r($attribute_taxonomies);
```

Answer (score 1):

**try:**

```
function GetProductAllParamsById($_idProduct = null) {

   if ( func_num_args() > 0 ) {

        $result = Array();
        $productAllAttr = get_post_meta( $_idProduct, '_product_attributes' );
        foreach ($productAllAttr as $value) {

            while (count($value) > 0) {

                $_instValue = array_pop($value);
                $_nameParam = $_instValue['name'];
                $_nameProductAttr = wc_get_product_terms( $_idProduct, $_nameParam, array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ); 

                array_push($result, [$_nameParam => $_nameProductAttr]);

            }

        }  

    }

    return isset($result) ? $result : null;
}
```

**Example:**

```
echo "<pre>";
echo print_r( GetProductAllParamsById($id_product) );
echo "</pre>";
```

**Return**:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pa_colors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Blue
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pa_customer] => Array
                (
                    [0] => someparam
                    [1] => sometwoparam
                )

        )

)
```